# How to query timestamp interval in JPA?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have one '`Log`' entity which contains information about temperature.
I'm trying to build a report which have two fields only:

```
quantity : this field will tell how much my search should look
interval : minutes, hours, days, months, years (this field tells me how much is the interval of the search
```

This is my `Log` entity:

```
public class Log implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private Timestamp time;

    private String value;
    // getters and setters ...
```

So when the user inform like `1 minute` I should look for the last minute (or 60 records at least).

Or if 1 month I should get all the data from the last month.

I'm trying something like this:

```
log.time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND log.time > :param
```

But how can I specify to minutes, hours ? What I mean is how can be more specific in my query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the time unit is "days":

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -quantity);
Date param = now.getTime();
```

Keep your query as is, and bind `param` to the `:param` request parameter.

For other intervals, do the same, but with the appropriate Calendar field (HOUR_OF_DAY, MINUTE, etc.) instead of Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH.

Comment: It works, thanks!
Just one correction, the .add method is :
now.add(Calendar.MONTH, -months) : first the current day, month, year then how many days, months, years you want to subtract (or sum)